# Fabric crashlytics to Firebase migration

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have an app that was using fabric crashlytics. New version of this app will be using firebase service for crash logging, but I would like to have some visibility of current users (that are still on fabric sdk).

According to https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android :

> The Fabric SDK is now deprecated and will continue reporting your app's crashes until November 15, 2020.

Where can I find these reports? I can't sign in to fabric dashboard anymore and they are not showing in firebase console.

Answer (score 2):

*firebaser here*

Since the Fabric dashboard has been shut down, the crash reports from apps using the legacy SDKs are only visible in the Firebase console.

If you are having a hard time getting this to work, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Will my app just stop sending crash reporting or is there a chance that the app will crash if I don't migrate?

Comment: The app definitely shouldn't crash, but if you have problems [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting